# scaling issues for vinyl printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, vinyl

I am currently printing 30 shirts for a sports company. All of which have a different sponsorship that must conform to the 14.5cm x 4cm area.

[image: screenshot of illustrator]

The issue I have is that if I use the same font size for all sponsors, the smaller names such as (OSI) will only be 1cm in height which is not ideal. What would be the best scaling method to make sure the design is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" method.

The only real way to create balance is to *visually* determine how one name is weighted among the others. You merely have to **eyeball** it.

All formulaic methods will inevitably leave the larger items overpowering and the smaller items underwhelming.